# Data binding on Windows phone 8 live tiles

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone, live-tile

I am trying to bind some strings in the 'backcontent' of the live tiles in my Windows Phone 8 app to change the text depending on the languaje of the smartphone but I can not find the way. The tiles, with an static string are working fine.
This is the 'tokens' block of my 'WMAppManifest.xml':

```
<Tokens>
  <PrimaryToken TokenID="PhoMod_VToken" TaskName="_default">
    <TemplateFlip >
      <SmallImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\IconicTileSmall.png</SmallImageURI>
      <Count>0</Count>
      <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\IconicTileMedium.png</BackgroundImageURI>
      <Title>PhoMod 3D
      </Title>
      <BackContent>Capture, view and share your world in 3D</BackContent>
      <BackBackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\IconicTileMedium_Back.png</BackBackgroundImageURI>
      <BackTitle>PhoMod 3D
      </BackTitle>
      <LargeBackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\IconicTileLarge.png</LargeBackgroundImageURI>
      <LargeBackContent>Capture, view and share your world in 3D</LargeBackContent>
      <LargeBackBackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\IconicTileLarge_Back.png</LargeBackBackgroundImageURI>
      <DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">
      </DeviceLockImageURI>
      <HasLarge>True</HasLarge>
    </TemplateFlip>
  </PrimaryToken>
</Tokens>
```

Please suggest a way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to bind values to WMAppManifest.xml. You need to programatically create new tile with text that you want and update the default one.

Check these links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206971%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Live_Tile_Templates_in_Windows_Phone_8

Comment: Thanks @Parad1s3. I tried and it works but, How can I lounch the code to generate the tile when the user touch the "pin to start" on the context menu displayed when you perform a long tap on the app from the app list?

Comment: That is not possible. However it does not matter. You can update primary tile even when the app is not pinned on user's start screen and the next time they pin it, system will use updated version.